# The size of tensor a (516) must match the size of tensor b (513) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, resolution

first i run an algorithm with its dataset and that was ok. the link of the code is in the following : [EDSR-**PyTorch**](https://github.com/sanghyun-son/EDSR-PyTorch)
(What this code does is that it receives an image with two modes of high and low resolution and improves the quality of the image with low resolution image and finally compares the improved image with the image with high resolution to check the quality of the improvement. does So, the input images are two high and low resolution images from the same photo.)

After that i tried to used my **RGB** dataset to test and run this code, but i got this error :

```
The size of tensor a (516) must match the size of tensor b (513) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

**Now i wanto to know, how can i fix this error?**

As an additional explanation, I changed the size of my input image to 513 but still got the same error:
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 1

Comment: Did you find a solution to it yet?